# What is the difference between AME and AME Zion Churches

Tags: protestantism

From (limited) personal experience, A.M.E. and A.M.E. Zion churches hold very similar structure, theology, and culture. What are the principle differences? Are there subtle separations in these points, or are they realistically simply two different political entities?

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, the [AME-Zion denomination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Methodist_Episcopal_Zion_Church) originated among African American Methodists in New York, and the AME denomination originated among African American Methodists around Philadelphia, both around 1800. Otherwise the histories of the two bodies are similar, and in 2012, they agreed to enter full communion with each other, and other Methodist bodies.

Comment: But how are they different? Are they different? I've read the Wikipedia entries and am still wondering.

Comment: The main difference is likely the different histories. There theology is similar, and the church governance is similar. Otherwise the differences might not be significant (or even noticeable) to an outsider. .

Comment: – can you add that to your answer?